# How do I call a xml file using xml extension with Ifinity Friendly url module in DNN?

Tags: xml, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I have a problem trying to make working a url rewriting. I have a DNN website and for url redirects we are using the iFinity Friendly Urls module.

We have defined some urls in the SiteUrls.config file of the DNN application. We have this redirect rule:

```
  <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>/sitemap.aspx</LookFor>
    <SendTo>/sitemap.xml</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
```

This is working correctly when we call for this url: 
http://mysite.com/sitemap.aspx

Even though, when we try to call the file directly, using an url like this:
http://mysite.com/sitemap.xml

**It doesn't work!!**

We configured the Regex Settings section of the iFinity module, so we have the following in our web.config file:

```
<friendlyUrl defaultProvider="iFinity.UrlMaster">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="iFinity.UrlMaster" type="iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, iFinity.UrlMaster.FriendlyUrlProvider" urlFormat="HumanFriendly" replaceSpaceWith="-" pageExtensionUsage="Never" forceLowerCase="true" useBaseFriendlyUrls="Search Results" useSiteUrlsRegex="/rss\.aspx|Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler\.ashx|BannerClickThrough\.aspx|/Admin/[^/]+/Tabid/\d+/.*default\.aspx|/Host/[^/]+/Tabid/\d+/.*default\.aspx|/sitemap\.xml" ignoreRegex="(?&lt;!linkclick\.aspx.+)(?:\.pdf$|\.gif$|\.png($|\?)|\.css$|\.js($|\?)|\.jpg$|\.html$|\.htm$|\.axd($|\?)|\.swf$|\.flv$|\.ico$|\.xml($|\?)|\.txt$)" />
        <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="humanfriendly" />
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS7 try adding this after the regular SiteMap handler

```
      <add name="SitemapXmlHandler" path="Sitemap.xml" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what is happening when you try to go straight to sitemap.xml.

Try telling UrlMaster to ignore sitemap.xml like this:

```
<add name="iFinity.UrlMaster" type="iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, iFinity.UrlMaster.FriendlyUrlProvider" urlFormat="HumanFriendly" replaceSpaceWith="-" pageExtensionUsage="Never" forceLowerCase="true" useBaseFriendlyUrls="Search Results" useSiteUrlsRegex="/rss\.aspx|Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler\.ashx|BannerClickThrough\.aspx|/Admin/[^/]+/Tabid/\d+/.*default\.aspx|/Host/[^/]+/Tabid/\d+/.*default\.aspx|sitemap\.xml" ignoreRegex="(?&lt;!linkclick\.aspx.+)(?:\.pdf$|\.gif$|\.png($|\?)|\.css$|\.js($|\?)|\.jpg$|\.html$|\.htm$|\.axd($|\?)|\.swf$|\.flv$|\.ico$|\.xml($|\?)|\.txt$)" />`
```

I removed the / from sitemap.xml in the `useSiteUrlsRegex`